# powerpoint vba stack

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In PowerPoint VBA, I am storing the selected multiple shapes in an array variable. I want it to be stored in stack. Is there any ways to do it?

Currently I am using set command to store the multiple shapes. But, if I delete those shapes, the stored shapes in the array are gone. (Guess, those shapes were in Heap).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
Balu.

Comment: Your array only has a reference to the shapes - shapes can't exist except on a slide (or arguably on the clipboard if you `Cut` one) so I don't think you can do what you want.